# Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop for KVM

Tags: server, kvm-virtualization

I need to deploy a bare metal server and install ubuntu for KVM Virtualization purposes only.
What's better fit, Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop?

Are there any major differences regarding Virtualization between the two?

Comment: There is no difference "regarding virtualization." If you want a graphical environment, select Ubuntu Desktop. If you want shell-only, select Ubuntu Server. For most folks, the choice is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of Virtualization, "Ubuntu Server" and "Ubuntu Desktop", both have a difference.

The core system is same, but Server version is optimized for server usage such as Web server ,DB server and etc. And most important thing is Server version has no Desktop Environment installed. This makes computer use less resource.

Desktop version, unlike Server version, it'll use more resource compare to Server version. But You can do video editing, watch Youtube video and most importantly, you have desktop environment.

Now back to your question. Your server role is Virtualization.
In this case, install "Ubuntu Server" version for optimizing resource usage.
And then, access that server remotely using OpenSSH or something.

However, if you want to manage your server like a Windows Server Desktop,
you can install "Ubuntu Desktop" and then install Linux KVM.

My recommend is "Choose Ubuntu Server".

Hope this answer help

Comment: More a comment then an answer. The OP is looking for an opinion which is actually off topic.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.
I have successfully installed an Ubuntu Server version and added a Desktop Environment for the server.
Now, I'm trying to figure out how to work with netplan tool over the legacy network manager. It seems that there are some conflicts between the two tools.